# Why using the queen is not a good idea in this case?

Tags: tactics

I am a new [and a late] comer to chess. I started practicing on [chessacademy.com](https://www.chesscademy.com) where I got [this exercise](https://www.chesscademy.com/tactics/15083):

```
r1bqk1nr/ppp2pp1/4p2p/8/1bPnN3/5N2/PP1B1PPP/R2QKB1R w KQkq - 1 13
```

According to the site, the best move is ♗b4 and then it asks the following:

> [Why not accomplish the same thing by Qa4+...Qxb4?]

I can't see why not? Any hints?

Comment: You are missing the knight fork on `c2`.  After `1.Qa4+ Bd7 2.Qxb4 Nc2+ 3.Kd1 Nxb4 ` you would lose the queen...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff, thank you !! can you post it as an answer so I can accept

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer... I am glad I have helped. Best regards until next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the knight fork on `c2`. After `1.Qa4+ Bd7 2.Qxb4 Nc2+ 3.Kd1 Nxb4` you would lose the queen...

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question can be answered by using an online engine connected with a chessboard editor. Since you need to get the FEN to enter this position here you might as well use that editor and play it against computer: http://www.apronus.com/chess/playcomputer/?fen=0r1bqk1nrXppp2pp1X4p2pX8X1bPnN3X5N2XPP1B1PPPXR2QKB1R_w_KQkq_-_0_1

The game will go 1.Qa4+ Bd7 2.Qxb4 Nc2+

Hope this helps next time.

Comment: That suggestion is of last resort, if at all: It is far better to figure it out yourself than to just toss it at an engine. you get tactically lazy doing that. When you start doing really difficult tactical and positional puzzles, you learn nothing by throwing it at fritz. The best thing to do is to keep that position at hand and keep trying, and trying, and trying. It's not a race. There is nothing more satisfying than solving a chess brain-burner that took you a while to figure out. Any monkey can use fritz.

Comment: My suggestion meant that it is better to use that online resource and get the answer immediately than post it here as a question. The effort is the same but the effect is much quicker.